# Packaging WIN app on OSX triggers request for Wine install. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, wine

I've successfully been using Electron on OSX (10.11.6) for months to build and package OSX and WIN apps. I am currently using `electron v1.7.3` and `"electron-packager" "^8.5.2"` and haven't updated anything for a while.

Today when I went to package a WIN app I got an alert about a need to install Wine, with an option to install. (I should have taken a screenshot to log the full message.) I opted to install Wine and the build proceeded normally. The app tests ok running Windows 10 under emulation with VMWare Fusion.

There were no terminal messages aside from the usual:

> Packaging app for platform win32 ia32 using electron v1.7.3

Does anyone know why this alert might have been triggered? Nothing on my system has changed (that I know of) since the last time I packaged apps – so I would like to understand what might have occurred. I didn't update my package.json or `npm` or include any additional npm packages.

Comment: How does your build command look like?

Comment: @kontrollanten – I am using `"electron-packager"` and haven't looked at its internals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

electron-packager [is using Wine for building Win dist on non-Win platforms.](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager#building-windows-apps-from-non-windows-platforms) Wine [released a new version five days ago](https://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git/?a=shortlog;h=refs/tags/wine-2.0.3) So what happened was that electron-packager triggered Wine to start, which checked for updates and prompted you to install it. You should feel safe :)

Comment: Ah. That makes sense.